Determining the minimal index where lexicographically different lists diverge in Lean 4
I'm trying to define the smallest index at which two lexicographically different lists of equal length diverge. This is what I have so far:
import Mathlib.Data.Fintype.Basic

def diff_list_ind (k m : List ℕ) (h0 : k < m) (h1 : k.length = m.length) : ℕ :=
  if k.head? = m.head? then
    0
  else
    sorry

How it should work would be if I have lists: l1 := [0, 1, 2] and
l2 := [0, 2, 1], then it would return 1. The issue right now is I'm not quite sure how to iterate the process of checking the first entry and discarding them if they are equal, in my definition. Thanks in advance!

You can use recursion to work on the tail of the lists if the heads are equal. Let's start by sketching out a more general version, to avoid keeping useless assumptions in the local hypothesis, which can increase the burden of working through the definition
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  sorry

Note that I have generalized lists of integers to any lists, that the index returned is guaranteed to be within bounds. Furthermore, we just need to assume that the two lists are different, not specific order is assumed. We also need a technicality, which is DecidableEq α, so that we can actually test if two elements of α are equal. Don't mind that until you have understood the rest of the code.
Now, I have mentioned working by recursion. To do so, let's split cases, depending on whether the lists passed in argument are empty lists or cons
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ => sorry
  | [], [] => sorry

Note that, because we have an assumption that l₁ and l₂ have the same length, Lean automatically rules out impossible cases in the pattern match for us: indeed, we don't have to consider the case [], hd₁::tl₁.
We can also rule out immediately the case [], [], because then the two lists would be equal, which is an immediate contradiction with the assumption h₀. Indeed, the contradiction tactic takes care of that automatically.
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ => sorry
  | [], [] => by contradiction

What's left to do is the interesting case. Here, there are two possibilities: either hd₁ = hd₂, in which case we must recurse, or we have found the first index where the two lists are different.
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      sorry
    else
      sorry
  | [], [] => by contradiction

we have used the syntax if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then ... else ... so that the fact h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ (resp. h₂ : hd₁ ≠ hd₂) can be added to the local hypothesis in each branch of the if. This is going to be useful later on. Now, else branch is the easy case, we just need to return 0
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      sorry
    else
      .mk 0 sorry
  | [], [] => by contradiction

(the remaining sorry is the proof that 0 is indeed an in-bound index, we'll take care of that later on).
For the other case, we essentially just want to recursively call our function on the tails, and add 1 to the result (because the recursive call finds the index just in the tails, not in the original lists)
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      .mk (1 + diff_index tl₁ tl₂ sorry sorry) sorry
    else
      .mk 0 sorry
  | [], [] => by contradiction

Again, we have used .mk ... sorry because we want to return the index alongside a proof that it is inbound. There algorithm is fully sketched out, now there are some few technical points that remain to be fixed: we need to convince Lean that, in our recursive call, the hypothesis still hold. Let's start with the first one, proving that the tails are different.
We'll write a named intermediate result to make things clearer:
have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
  sorry

The strategy that we will adopt is reuse the hypothesis h₀, using the argument that, if the lists are different, but the head are equal, it must be that the difference lies in the tails. Hence, we'll use our local hypothesis h₂ to simplify h₀:
have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
  rw [h₂] at h₀
  sorry

now h₀ : hd₂ :: tl₁ ≠ hd₂ :: tl₂. As stated before, this can be simplified
have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
  rw [h₂] at h₀
  simp at h₀
  sorry

now h₀ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂. We have won! The hypothesis matches the goal.
have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
  rw [h₂] at h₀
  simp at h₀
  exact h₀

The second hypothesis is even simpler to prove, using the same schema, except this time we don't even need to use a hypothesis to simplify an other hypothesis, the pattern matching has already done that for us:
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
        rw [h₂] at h₀
        simp at h₀
        assumption
      .mk (1 + diff_index tl₁ tl₂ tl₁_neq_tl₂ (by simp at h₁; assumption)) sorry
    else
      .mk 0 sorry
  | [], [] => by contradiction

(I'll let you hover over that proof if you want to see exactly how things evolve).
Now, the very last technicality to take care of is the in-bound matter. For the else branch case, this is very easy: the lists are non-empty, so the index 0 must be inbound. This very simple reasoning can be entirely automated with simp:
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
        rw [h₂] at h₀
        simp at h₀
        assumption
      .mk (1 + diff_index tl₁ tl₂ tl₁_neq_tl₂ (by simp at h₁; assumption)) sorry
    else
      .mk 0 (by simp)
  | [], [] => by contradiction

For the other case, it is only marginally more complicated. Here, we use the fact that the index returned by the recursive call has to be in bound for the tails, so it has to be one less than the maximum inbound index for our lists l₁ and l₂, meaning that if we add 1, we should still be inbound. We are going to split this argument into two parts: one part which takes care of every arithmetic details, and the other being the main point of the argument, that is, the index of the recursive call has to be inbound for the tails.
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
        rw [h₂] at h₀
        simp at h₀
        assumption
      .mk (1 + diff_index tl₁ tl₂ tl₁_neq_tl₂ (by simp at h₁; assumption)) <| by
        simp_arith
        sorry
    else
      .mk 0 (by simp)
  | [], [] => by contradiction

Indeed, the sorry_arith tactic simplifies the goal until the only remaining thing to be shown is that the index of the recursive call is inbound. This is taken care by the fact that any number in Fin n is less that n, which is named in Lean Fin.isLt.
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] (l₁ l₂ : List α) (h₀ : l₁ ≠ l₂) (h₁ : l₁.length = l₂.length) : Fin l₁.length :=
  match l₁, l₂ with
  | hd₁::tl₁, hd₂::tl₂ =>
    if h₂ : hd₁ = hd₂ then
      have tl₁_neq_tl₂ : tl₁ ≠ tl₂ := by
        rw [h₂] at h₀
        simp at h₀
        assumption
      .mk (1 + diff_index tl₁ tl₂ tl₁_neq_tl₂ (by simp at h₁; assumption)) <| by
        simp_arith
        apply Fin.isLt
    else
      .mk 0 (by simp)
  | [], [] => by contradiction


One approach (maybe not the best one, it depends) is to decouple the code and the assumptions on the lists.  There is a very natural generalization that works for any two lists regardless of there size or if they are different:
def diff_index {α : Type _} [DecidableEq α] : (List α) -> (List α) -> Nat
| [], _ => 0
| _, [] => 0
| (h1 :: t1), (h2 :: t2) =>
  if h1 != h2 then
    0
  else
    1 + (diff_index t1 t2)

#eval diff_index [0, 1, 2] [0, 2, 1]  -- 1 (same length, different lists)
#eval diff_index [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2]  -- 3 (same length, same lists)
#eval diff_index [0, 1] [0, 1, 2]     -- 2 (one subsequence of other)
#eval diff_index [0, 1, 2] [0, 3]     -- 1 (diff length, incomparable)

A simple mathematical description of this operator is the largest i <= (min l1.length l2.length) such that l1.take i = l2.take i.
If the lists are of equal length but different, the output is exactly as you want.  You can (and should) prove this in Lean.
If the lists are equal then it will return the length of the list.  If one list is a subsequence of the other, then it will return the length of the subsequence.
I often find it helps to generalize definitions a bit.  Sooner than later I'm looking for the generalized version anyway.
